# Where can I visit the only two escalators in Wyoming?

Tags: usa, factoids, wyoming

Someone was showing me a list of things learned in 2013, and one of their facts was that the state of Wyoming, in the US, only has two escalators in the whole state.

Where are these two escalators? (Not just the city, but the building, preferably, and whether it's publicly accessible)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Huffington Post](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2013/07/18/wyoming-has-only-2-escalators_n_3616861.html), both are in Casper, at the First National Bank and the Hilltop National Bank.